# Installing PCL library using vcpkg on Windows 10, but building failed during installation

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2022, vcpkg

I used vcpkg to install the PCL library, but encountered the following error. vcpkg is the latest.  and placed in `D:\vcpkg`. How should I solve this problem?

I use VS2022 and I also failed to use this command:

```
vcpkg install pcl:x64-windows --x-use-aria2
```

Comment: What error did you see?

Comment: Copy and paste your output and format it as code (ctrl + K or toolbar button), so we  can see exactly what is happening.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.